# Purpose of the injection of an interface with multiple implementations

Tags: java, interface, factory, inject

Consider a factory like the following:

```
public interface SomeFactory {
    public SomeValue createSomething(SomeKey key);
}
```

Furthermore we got some implementation of SomeFactory:

```
public class SomeFactoryImpl implements SomeFactory {

    @Override
    public SomeValue createSomething(Key key) {
        // some logic
    }

}
```

Let us consider a class which wants to use this factory:

```
public class SomeClass{

@Inject
private SomeFactory someFactory;

    public String someMethod(Key someKey) {
        someFactory.createSomething(someKey);
        // some more logic
    }
}
```

What is the advantage of using an interface for the factory in this situation? I thought the following:

Let us assume I want to use another implementation for my factory:

```
public class AnotherFactoryImpl implements SomeFactory {

    @Override
    public SomeValue createSomething(Key key) {
        // some logic
    }

}
```

Which factory will then be used with the @Inject-annotation? Would it be more appropriate to Inject the implementation itself, or do we always have just one implementation for the factory? Another possible answer: Is it not appropriate to use an interface for the factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of using an interface is, that you don't care which implementation you have in your hands, but solely using the interface's methods, which are common among all implementations. Don't forget, that you have to use the same method signature, including the same return value when overriding.

The injection mechanism works by name - so since you don't specify the value in `@Inject`, it looks for an object named `someFactory` and injects it, which is fine, since it's of type `SomeFactory`, no matter which implementation is behind. You may as well inject a specific implementation, which depends on your use case if you deal with the common behavior or a specific one. The instance you want to inject, has to be either bound to the scope you are using or there has to be a `Producer` which creates the object when needed for injection.

---

Edit: See my comments below for link to CDI usage and an easier architecture for this use case.

Comment: And which implementation will be used in the above example? SomeFactoryImpl or AnotherFactoryImpl?

Comment: @Chris311: None, since from your example it is not obvious what is available under the name `someFactory`. `@Inject` needs to be certain about what to inject - either you have a concrete class with an appropriate constructor which gets called before injecting (see [Java EE Tutorial on CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic004.htm)) or you have to have an `@Producer` and an appropriate qualifier to direct to the right producer for your injected bean (see Java EE Tutorial a few pages after the above one).

Comment: @Chris311: Check out [Adam Bien's article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/intondemand-1444614.html) on how to get rid of interfaces and factories for the use case above with Java EE.

Comment: So, is it even wise to provide an interface for my factory? At the moment I only got one implementation and one place in my code where the factory is used.

Comment: @Chris311: You probably know the rule to keep things simple in software architecture and not implement things prematurely, until you really need them. 1) You don't need to have a 1:1 relationship between interface and implementation; an interface is only reasonable, if you have at least 2 implementations. 2) A factory is a producer for certain specific objects, you don't need to wrap that in an interface again. 3) If you are using CDI (which can be done even outside Java EE), you can have qualified producers as explained in the links above and omit the factory.